# How can I stop media player in another activity?

Tags: android

I start mediaplayer like this:

```
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
    }
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.background);
    mp.start();
```

How can I stop in another activity? It continues to play in another activity. How can I use `onDestroy` in another activity?

Comment: in your current activity onPause use mp.stop(). When you navigate to second activity your 1st activity is paused

Comment: call the stop conde inside onPause

Comment: if you play across several activities, use a service.

Comment: You can't destroy one activity from another activity. But you can pause the media player by creating a new instance of MediaPlayer in the second activity and callind the 'stop' method !

Comment: What if you want to create a button in another activity which on click will stop mediaplayer which started in earlier activity ? how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 8):

Use the Separate class like below in your project.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class AudioPlay {

    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private static SoundPool soundPool;
    public static boolean isplayingAudio=false;
    public static void playAudio(Context c,int id){
         mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c,id);
         soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
         if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())           
         {
        isplayingAudio=true;
         mediaPlayer.start();             
         }          
     }
    public static void stopAudio(){     
         isplayingAudio=false;       
         mediaPlayer.stop();
    }   
}
```

**Playing the song**

```
`AudioPlay.playAudio(mContext, R.raw.audiofile);` // play it from your preferred activity. and you can change raw file to your path also its depends upon your requirement.
```

then 
stop the audio using this lines `AudioPlay.stopAudio();` from any activity. 
hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In 1st activity override onPause

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
            mp.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my **Kotlin** solution:

```
package com.programacionymas.myapp.services

import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaPlayer

object AudioPlay {
    var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    var lastResource: Int? = null

    fun playAudio(c: Context, id: Int, isLooping: Boolean = true) {
        createMediaPlayer(c, id)

        mediaPlayer?.let {
            it.isLooping = isLooping

            if (!it.isPlaying) {
                it.start()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createMediaPlayer(c: Context, id: Int) {
        // in case it's already playing something
        mediaPlayer?.stop()

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, id)
        lastResource = id
    }

    // usually used inside the Activity's onResume method
    fun continuePlaying(c: Context, specificResource: Int? = null) {
        specificResource?.let {
            if (lastResource != specificResource) {
                createMediaPlayer(c, specificResource)
            }
        }

        mediaPlayer?.let {
             if (!it.isPlaying) {
                it.start()
            }
        }
    }

    fun pauseAudio() {
        mediaPlayer?.pause()
    }

}
```

I started from [itsrajesh4uguys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/985369/itsrajesh4uguys)'s Java answer, and I applied these changes:

- Remove the Boolean attribute, since it was not being used
- Add an attribute to track the last loaded resource, this way I can continue playing it or replace with other resource
- Call the stop function before creating a new instance, to avoid overlapping

Finally I use it this way:

In the `onCreate` method:

```
AudioPlay.playAudio(this, R.raw.background_music)
```

In the `onResume` method:

```
AudioPlay.continuePlaying(this, R.raw.background_music)
```

In my case I had to specify the resource, because some of my Activities start playing another music sounds.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call stop an activity but from the activity itself to

achive this you can send the media player in a service and bind to the service in the activities you want to access it

Answer (score 0):

As you have started media player in first activity and wanted to stop in another activity, just call your second layout in first activity using layout inflater self instead of creating another activity.. and on second layout file just stop the media player by pressing a button

```
   public class FirstAvtivity extends Activity
   {  
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.first_activity_layoutfile);
     Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    //start the media player like how you were starting in your activity
// then after clicking button you will be navigated to new layout , there  
//  you can stop media player

       mPlayer.start();
      b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            updateLayout();


        }
    });

   }
    private void newUpdateLayout() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
     setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_disapr_scr, null));
    finalDismiss=(Button)findViewById(R.id.final_dismiss);
     finalDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"welcome to second 
 avtivity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             mPlayer.stop();
             finish();
         }
     });
   }
 }
```