# error (-38, 0) media player

Tags: android, live-streaming

Whenever i am trying to stop the media player in an another activity than i am getting an error:
 E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 64, mPlayer(0xa3baf580)
 E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)

```
MainActivity:
```

package radiofm.arabelradio;

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.io.IOException;

import static android.media.AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageButton id_play;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean prepared = false;
    boolean started =false;
    String stream ="http://arabelfm.ice.infomaniak.ch/arabelprodcastfm.mp3";
    //main_page contain arabel_photo player for radio



     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        id_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.id_play);
        id_play.setEnabled(false);
        //id_play.setText("LOADING");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        new PlayerTask().execute(stream);
        id_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (started){
                    started=false;
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                   // id_play.setText("PLAY");
                }
                else {
                    started=true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

                    //id_play.setText("PAUSE");
                }
            }
        });
        //main_page contain arabel_photo player for radio//////////////////////////:




        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, R.string.open,R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar() .setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar() .setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



    }




//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0] );
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared=true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            id_play.setEnabled(true);
            id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

            // id_play.setText("PLAY");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop () {
        super.onStop();
    }


        @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(started){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(started){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(prepared){
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //main_page contain arabel_photo player for radio//////////////////////////:



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

media player objected created in one activity can not be used in the another activity 
make another where you use the media player  to fragment or initialize the  media player in service so that u can access any where.

or

check this question answer
[How can I stop media player in another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690057/how-can-i-stop-media-player-in-another-activity)
 and check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices

Comment: what are u talking about ?

Comment: can you post the code of how your stopping the media player