# Background Music?

Tags: android

I already have a background music and its working using this code

```
MediaPlayer backgroundMusic;

backgroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(HomeActivity.this, R.raw.bgmusic);
backgroundMusic.start();
```

but when it finished it doesn't repeat how can I make loop?

also how to pause it for a while in other `classes` and resume it?

Comment: Why do you want to annoy your users (and the people close to them) with undesired music?

Comment: I don't have the intention to upload this in Google Play its only for my School Project what seems to be wrong?

Comment: We were just starting to learn android programming in school why need to vote down?

Comment: Well, it **is** a help center. But asking to be **spoon-fed** is much different fom asking a legit question.

Comment: You should quickly learn how to live in a community. You are not an isolated individual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use of setLooping(true) like the below code

```
MediaPlayer backgroundMusic;

backgroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(HomeActivity.this, R.raw.bgmusic);
  backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);
backgroundMusic.start();
```

Comment: is it possible to pause it or stop it in other `classes`?

Comment: Yes it is possible.you must use the separate class.this link can help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690057/how-can-i-stop-media-player-in-another-activity